# Change lockscreen date language iOS 6

Tags: ios, internationalization, language, screen-lock

When I first configured my new iPod touch 5th gen, I put "English" for iOS language. I then switched iOS to "Français (Canada)" in the General Settings/International. Everything look fine except one thing : The date displayed on the lockscreen which remains in english (Ex: Monday, 15 April). Even after restarting my iPod, the date is still in english.

Any idea how to have the date translated on the lockscreen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `Settings -> General -> International`, you need to change the `Region Format` settings to specify your desired region; I'm assuming you only changed the *`Language`* settings.

When I change Region Format to `French -> Canada`, my lockscreen appears with the correct French date format: `mardi 16 avril`.

Comment: Kinda confusing, since when I go in `Settings -> General -> International`, `Region Format` display only `Canada`, so I did not bother looking there since I thought it was already correct. BUT `French -> Canada` is not part of the available values there. It just switched to a random Region, went back and reset it to `Canada` and then it worked o_O

Comment: Bizarre. When I tapped French in the Region Format listing, I was taken to a screen that lets you pick *sub-*regions, and that's where I chose Canada. Glad you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 1):

The format and language of Date & Time (and other units of measure) are set in 
Settings -> General -> International -> Region Format.

These can be set independently of the language used throughout the rest of your iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Check out by going to Settings --> General --> Date & Time.

Comment: There isn't a language config there. There are 3 settings : 24-hour time, Set automatically and Time zone.